# ¿How to set automatically degree symbol in EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making an application in android studio where one of the data that I need to capture is the temperature of the person.

As shown in the image, the only thing that I did was place the degree symbol as default in the EditText. But I have to manually move the cursor to place the number before the symbol.

Does anyone know how I can make android place the degrees symbol automatically **AFTER** typing the temperature data in EditText?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be using **`TextWatcher`** for edit Text which has a callback function **`afterTextChanged(Editable s)`** in which you should put your desired String/char at the end by contacting like **`s.toString() + your_char`**

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    //here you are setting the data after the entry of temprature
    yourEditText.append(" \u00B0");

}
});
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher)

Comment: After implementing your answer in the application, for some reason when I select the EditText, the application crashes and does not let me write anything.

Comment: --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.form, PID: 18250
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available

Comment: please have a look at the updated answer, if error persists let me know

Comment: The problem was fixed, it no longer crashes, however the degree symbol is not generated automatically.

Comment: try removing the space